# Accessing private member of class in a vector and return it as a string

Tags: c++, class, vector, member

I am trying to create a vector of integers and then write it out through a function that would print the values with a certain width.

Say the `vector` was filled with `{1,2,3,4}` and the limiting width is `4`, then the output is:
    1 2
    2 4

Using `turntostring`, which converts data type into string and return int, I was able to turn int into string and get its size in my function that prints the vector.

```
turntostring(r.at(i)).size();
```

So at `i = 2`, I have `int = 4`, with the code above the return value is `1`.

It was fine until I have to do the same for a vector of classes and as I am trying to access the element in this class I am unable to use the same line of code above.

I tried to write a print function for the class and write this in order to obtain the same result:

```
r.at(i).print().size();
```

Print would take the class and return a string.

But I need to use the same line of code to access the size of the element as a requirement. Meaning the same line of code must work for a `vector` of type int and a `vector` of class with a member of type int for example:

```
class fake
{
    int num;
}

vector<int> r;
vector<fake> k;
```

I should be able to access each element in these two vectors and use `.size()` then use `turnintostring` on them.

Please let me know if there is some method that I do not know about.

Comment: "say the vector was filled with {1,2,3,4} and the limiting width is 4, then the outputis: 1 2 2 4". I'm afraid I don't understand what it is you're trying to do, could you make it a bit clearer?

Comment: I forgot to 4 space in order for that To show as code. What I meant to type is that the width would be a given int, let say 4. the width would limit how many characters can be on one line before a new line is made. so for the above: it would print 1 2 then next line 2 4. A space is added after one string is added, each element in the vector would get convert to a string through turnintostring in some other lien of code and it would code for that whole print process. The difficult part that I have is accessing a private member of a class with the normal .at() command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have `string turntostring(int)` then you just need a cast:

```
class fake
{
    int num;
public:
    operator int();
}
fake::operator int() {return num;}

turntostring(some_fake);
turntostring(3);
```

Comment: I do have something like that, or tried it. it work when I tried to  use r.at(i).print().size() to get the size of the element num from the class fake, but the same line of code would not work for a vector of type int.

Comment: That figures: int doesn't know how to do print(). You can use a cast operator like in my soon-to-appear edit.

Comment: I am not familiar with cast. Does it return the num value when use like this some_fake.int();

Comment: No need. With that operator in the class you can just use your object like an integer and it'll be automatically converted to one.

Comment: So if r is a vector of fakes, this line         /////       turntostring(r.at(i)).size();      //////      Would return the size of the member in fake?

Comment: Assuming turntostring is declared to take int and return string, then yes I think that should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, the code worked now! Have a good night. Also just for information, does this cast only work with int or can i do the opposite and create a cast of string or char? then use something like turnintoint and do the revert.

Comment: A class can define its own casts to pretty much anything. I'm not sure what you mean by "use something like turnintoint and do the revert"